# Get latest set of records as of a date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series

I'm using a time-series collection in MongoDb and want to query for the latest set of records as of (on or before) a date.
E.g. Querying for 2022-01-15 would return all the records in Set: abc

Querying for 2022-01-31 would return all records in Set: xyz.

```
ID: 1, Set: abc, Value: 100, AsAtDate: 2022-01-01
ID: 2, Set: abc, Value: 200, AsAtDate: 2022-01-01
ID: 3, Set: xyz, Value: 300, AsAtDate: 2022-01-31
ID: 4, Set: xyz, Value: 400, AsAtDate: 2022-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
collection.find().sort({AsAtDate: -1}, function(err, cursor){...});
```

This will sort your collection in descending order based on the date